# How to initialize text boxes and labels inside a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net-core

My program is supposed to calculate a final examination score by adding the percentages of four separate types of tests.

The percentages goes like this,

- 15% from Model Test 1
- 20% from Model Test 2
- 15% from the highest mark out of the two Class Tests (Class Test 1 and Class Test 2 )
- 50% from Final Exam Mark

I was advised to,

Create a **class** named **‘Student’** with all the required instance variables (test 1 marks, test 2 marks, class test 1 marks, class test 2 marks).

Create a **constructor** to initialize all the instance variables.

Write a **method** within the class to;

- **calculate the final mark**
- **determine whether it is a pass or fail (message)**
- **display the mark and the message result**

When you clicked the ‘Calculate Final Mark’ button, the **method needs to be called** and display the output. (Hint: You have to create an object from the Student class and call the method)

Here's the code tried.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public double Mt1;  //Module test 1
        public double Mt2;  //Module test 2
        public double Ct1;  //Class test 1
        public double Ct2;  //Class test 2
        public double Em;   //Exam Mark

        public void getMarks()
        {
            Student stu = new Student();
            double Fm = 0;      //Final mark
            string dis = " ";   //Display

            Mt1 = Mt1 * 0.15;
            Mt2 = Mt2 * 0.2;

            if (Ct1 > Ct2)
            {
                Ct1 = Ct1 * 0.15;
            }

            else
            {
                Ct2 = Ct2 * 0.15;
            }

            Em = Em * 0.5;

            Fm = Mt1 + Mt2 + Ct1 + Ct1 + Em;

            if (Fm >= 50)
            {
                dis = "The final mark of the student is " + Fm.ToString() + "% /n The result is a Pass";
            }

            else
            {
                dis = "The final mark of the student is " + Fm.ToString() + "% /n The result is a Fail";
            }

            display.Text = dis;  //Error
        }
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student one = new Student()
        {
            Mt1 = Convert.ToDouble(mt1.Text),
            Mt2 = Convert.ToDouble(mt2.Text),
            Ct1 = Convert.ToDouble(ct1.Text),
            Ct2 = Convert.ToDouble(ct2.Text),
            Em = Convert.ToDouble(em.Text),
        };

        one.getMarks();            
    }
```

I've created separate text boxes to enter the marks, and a label to display the output.

However, I'm having trouble **initializing** the **Text Boxes** and the **Label** inside my constructor.

My code is obviously wrong. Please help me correct it as per the question.

Comment: What exactly is your trouble? Doesn't compile? Doesn't work as expected? Btw you are not initializing the textboxes and the labels. You are initializing member variables of Student. Which you should do by providing parameters to the constructor instead of accessing global objects.

Comment: @SvenBardos, my code doesn't compile. I edited the code to show the errors

Comment: That's because the textboxes are not visible (wrong scope) within the student class. And that's a good thing. Don't try to make them visible somehow. Instead pass the values needed into student and get the results out of Student as needed.

Comment: @SvenBardos, OK so I edited my code again. But I'm still confused about how to display the results through the 'display' label. I can't figure out how

Comment: check the last point of my hints.  display.Text = student.GetMarks();

Comment: Cool :-) If the community was able to solve your problem, please consider to accept one of the given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing the TextBox instances from inside your class, pass the TextBox.Text values to your student class in your Button_Click event handler.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student one = new Student()
    {
        Mt1 = Convert.ToDouble(mt1.Text),
        Mt2 = Convert.ToDouble(mt2.Text),
        Ct1 = Convert.ToDouble(ct1.Text),
        Ct2 = Convert.ToDouble(ct2.Text),
        Em = Convert.ToDouble(em.Text)
    };

    display.Text = one.getMarks();
}
```

Change your getMarks() method to return string instead of void. Then, instead of setting the textbox, just

```
return dis;
```

Comment: how do I display the results through the display label?

Comment: I will add that if you can wait for an hour.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer but writing on the phone. Please let me know if this is ok.

Comment: Yes please! That would be a huge help! Coding gets me so confused. I can't figure out what to put and where...

Comment: I’ve put it, just check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

I can not give you full solution but some hints:

Pass the required parameters into Student like this:

```
public Student(double mt1, double mt2, double ct1, double ct2)
{
        //Store values in private members or in properties.
}
```

Create a student like this:

```
double mt1 = Convert.ToDouble(mt1.Text);
double mt2 = Convert.ToDouble(mt2.Text);
double ct1 = Convert.ToDouble(ct1.Text);
double ct2 = Convert.ToDouble(ct2.Text);
double em = Convert.ToDouble(em.Text);
Student student = new Student(mt1, mt2, ct1, ct2, em);
```

Get the result from GetMarks() (your version doesn't return anything, you need to 
change that)

```
   display.Text = student.GetMarks();
```

Keep in mind that there is no reason Student class needs to "know" about textboxes, labels and stuff. So keep all this out of the class and focus on things that are relevant for a student. 
Textboxes, labels, etc are things of the UI and belong to the Form-class.